# Home PC doesn't recognize exFAT formatted SD-Card but work PC does

Tags: windows-7, micro-sd-card, exfat

I have a Micro-SD card formatted in my smartphone as exFAT. I can work with the card (read and write) on my work laptop (Windows 7 Pro) but my home PC (Windows 7 Home) does not recognize the card and says it's unformatted. It's very strange because Windows natively supports exFAT.

What could be the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure the card reader in your home PC can read this type of SD card (SDHC/SDXC)?

Comment: @DanielB Good point. No, I'm not. I'll check it with another card reader.

Comment: @DanielB Card reader it was! You can make it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With SD cards (even Micro-SD), there’s many types: Plain SD (up to 2 GiB), SDHC (“High Capacity”, up to 32 GiB) and SDXC (“eXtended Capacity”, up to 2 TiB). Apparently, SDUC (“Ultra Capacity”, up to 128 TiB) has also been announced. (Wonder what comes after that!)

A card reader has to support a specific type to be able to access it. Then there’s also UHS-II with additional data pins, though those are optional.

Depending on the operating mode of the card reader, the operating system has to have support, too.

**tl;dr**: Your home PC probably does not support your SD card type.